# How to use strings in pagination instead of numbers

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have a blog page that displays one article per page with next and previous links. Which i built with  codeigniter pagination class. I would like my blog single article links to look like this
http://example.com/blog/article/i-am-an-article-title

Instead of

http://example.com/blog/article/1

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['page_query_string']=TRUE;

$config['query_string_segment'] = 'your_string';
```

Comment: This works if you have a url like so http://example.com?page_per=7.applying the settings above lets you to be able to change page per with your custom query string. So if i use $config['page_query_string']=TRUE;

$config['query_string_segment'] = 'your_string';  i get http://example.com?your_string=7.